# Computing singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

could you help me solving this questions,please

> Let $D^2$ be a 2-dimensional disc and $M$ be the Möbius strip. Note that the boundary of
>   both $D^2$ and of $M$ is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$.
>
> (a) Consider the space 
>   $X := (D^2 U D^2)/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation which
>   identifes the boundaries of the first and second copy of $D^2$. Compute the singular
>   homology of $X$.
>
> (b) Consider the space 
>   $Y := (D^2 U M)/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation which
>   identifes the boundaries of $D^2$ and $M$. Compute the singular
>   homology of $Y$.
>
> (c) Consider the space 
>   $Z := (M U M)/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation which
>   identifes the boundaries of the first and second copy of $M$. Compute the singular
>   homology of $Z$.

Thank you

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: hi adeel, actually i do not know how to solve this quation?

Comment: Can you see that these spaces are homeomorphic to more familiar ones?

Comment: do you mean a circle?

Comment: No.  If you are having trouble with this I would recommend taking a step back from singular homology and reading a basic book like Essential Topology by Crossley, or Intuitive Topology by Prasolov.

Comment: Thank you
i think The surfaces are (a) the sphere, (b) th projective plane, and (c) the Klein bottle.
Is it ture?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: so now i have to compute the singular homology for those spaces?

Comment: Yes, but the simplicial or cellular homologies will be easier to compute.

Comment: You really shouldn't just post virtually all of a coursework assignment on a forum. People don't have any problem trying to help you with the understanding of a subject, but just posting the questions here is only likely to infuriate people.

Comment: This is a question from a take-home exam which is in-progress. I kindly ask that all well-meaning respondents wait until Saturday April 27th to answer this question.